# Does the Mac version of BitDefender detect Windows malware?

Tags: windows, malware

I need to know if [BitDefender](https://www.bitdefender.com) scans incoming emails and external drives?

I emailed BitDefender's support after installing the trial but never received a reply.

I currently use [Kaspersky Internet Security](https://usa.kaspersky.com/internet-security) but would consider switching when my Kaspersky subscription runs, as long as BitDefender can at least scans incoming emails.

Comment: Given the lack of a reply from BitDefender's technical support, are you still willing to give them your business?

Comment: Yeah, getting ignored while you are setting up first dates is a great thing to look for as is an over eager wooer - you need to figure out how you’ll be treated once you commit $

Answer (score 2):

The [BitDefender website](https://www.bitdefender.co.uk/solutions/antivirus-for-mac.html) does claim that the Mac version will remove Windows malware. I can't find anything specifically mentioning email or network drives, but it would be a significant and unlikely oversight.

It's worth pointing out that BitDefender contains (and has contained) [security vulnerabilities](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-5936/Bitdefender.html) that can be exploited in itself.

Answer (score 1):

From Bitdefender Total Security User's Guide, Publication date 05/12/2019, on page 74 of [bitdefender_ts_2019_userguide_en.pdf](https://download.bitdefender.com/resources/media/materials/2019/userguides/en_EN/bitdefender_ts_2019_userguide_en.pdf?ver=1):

> 4.1.1. On-access scanning (real-time protection)
>
> Bitdefender provides real-time protection against a wide range of threats by scanning all accessed files and email messages.

From page 73:

> Bitdefender automatically scans any removable media that is connected
>   to the computer to make sure it can be safely accessed. For more
>   information, refer to “Automatic scan of removable media” (p. 86).

From page 86:

> 4.1.3. Automatic scan of removable media
>
> Bitdefender automatically detects when you connect a removable storage device to your computer
>   and scans it in the background when the Autoscan option is enabled.
>   This is recommended to prevent threats from infecting your computer.
>
> Detected devices fall into one of these categories:
>
> ● CDs/DVDs
>  ● Flash
>   drives, such as flash pens and external hard-drives
>  ● mapped (remote)
>   network drives.

Continued on next page:

> You can configure automatic scan separately for each category of
>   storage devices. Automatic scan of mapped network drives is off by
>   default.